# A study about blood differences and the risk for COVID-19

Tags: covid-19, infection, blood, virus, research

On [healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health-news/does-your-blood-type-increase-your-risk-for-coronavirus#What-the-study-says) it's mentioned  a recent [study](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.03.11.20031096v1) that came out of Wuhan, China; it’s published on a website, but hasn’t yet been reviewed by peers.

> In the study, scientists looked at the blood types of 2,173 people who had been diagnosed with COVID-19 and compared that with the blood types of the general population in that region.
>
> They found that in the normal population, type A was 31 percent, type B was 24 percent, type AB was 9 percent, and type O was 34 percent.
>
> In those with the virus, type A was 38 percent, type B was 26 percent, type AB was 10 percent, and type O was 25 percent.
>
> The researchers concluded that “blood group A had a significantly higher risk for COVID-19 compared with non-A blood groups. Whereas blood group O had a significantly lower risk for the infectious disease compared with non-A blood groups.”

In 'non-medical' or easy to follow terms/explanations, Why is that?

Why does blood type A is more at risk?

and Why does blood type O has less risk?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

In simpler terminology than used in the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1101/2020.03.11.20031096) referred to, the observation has been made before that there is a blood group susceptibility to certain viruses, and that SARS appeared to affect blood group O individuals less than group A.

Group O individuals possess antibodies against the antigens displayed by group A individuals on their cells.  These antibodies, anti-A, interfered with the binding of the SARS-CoV-2 spike protein to the ACE2 receptor - like a form of neutralizing antibody or natural protection.  Their small studies suggested that Group O individuals had 60% of the risk of the full population and Group A individuals an increased risk of 120%.  AB Blood group risk ranged from 148-200% increased risk.

Whether that is clinically useful remains to be seen.  Could pooled immunoglobulin from Group O individuals help infected sick Covid-19 patients? Would any vaccine directed against this region of the virus be ineffective in Group A/B individuals because they would be trying to create a vaccine against self antigens?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.